# Java - Confused with object assignment

Tags: java, oop, object

[the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cw2OB.png)

I have been following the Lynda.com java tutorials for the last few days now and I am quite confused by this one part in particular involving the line:

```
p1 = new Property(230000, "Estate", 2.0, 2, 3)
```

I have added p1 to the ArrayList mls twice now but when I make the Property p1 object equal a new object of the Property class, what exactly is happening here?

Am I changing the initial value of p1 or creating a new object from the 'object p1'?

Comment: Do not post links to images for code. Include the code in your post (use the Edit capability). Make sure to indent your code 4 spaces or hilight it and click the `{}` button in the editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object variables in Java are always references.

`Property p1 = new Property(230000, "Estate", 2.0, 2, 3)`

This allocated a new Property object on the heap and set p1 to a reference to it.

`p1 = some_other_property;`

This made p1 now a reference to the same Property referenced by the variable `some_other_property`. We copied the reference.

`someFunction(p1)`

This copied the reference `p1` into the argument of someFunction. Notice that none of this manipulation of the reference actually changed the Property object, we just mucked about with references to it.

This also means that you can have multiple references that point to the same underlying object. If you add p1 to an ArrayList twice, then do an operation that mutates the object, both entries in the ArrayList will reflect the change (as both refer to the same thing)

This question provides some related and interesting details:

[Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of the class `Property` and setting the variable `p1` to refer to it.

In your example code, the variable p1 is being re-used. First it points to the first created object, then that reference is stored in the ArrayList and p1 gets a new value (a reference to the second object). Then that second object reference is also stored in the ArrayList

Comment: So the object p1 created in the beginning is different from the variable p1 creating the new instance of the Property class?

Comment: Yes. When you use the `new` operator you are creating a new object on the heap. Remember that your object variables are really references: assignment copies references. The only place new objects come from is the `new` operator.

So, in your program, p1 is a reference that points to the "Land" property on line 15, but then is reassigned to point to the shiny new "Estate" property on line 17. Both of the underlying Property objects still exist at this point, as the ArrayList will hold a reference to them and prevent them from being garbage collected.(Stuff with no references to it gets deleted)

Answer (score 0):

When you do `p1 = new Property(230000, "Estate", 2.0, 2, 3)` a new `Property` object is created in memory and it's reference is set in the `p1` variable.

Let's say the pointer location is 100.
So when you do `arrayList.add(p1); 100 is added to the list.`

Now when you change `p1` by another `new` now the reference got changed to point the new object. Let's the pointer is 200.
So the arraylist now has 200 and 100.

In this case even if, the actual reference variable `p1` has lost the old object reference, but the list has both references 100 and 200. So it will have both the values.

**Note :** `ArrayList` allows duplicate insertion.